# Magento 2.2 theme designing not applying

Tags: theme, magento-2.2.1

I am learning to create a theme in Magento 2.2, the directory structure for the theme is as follows

> a) app/design/frontend/compstore/web/css/source/_theme.less

_theme.less code is as follows

```
   //Change navigation background color
@navigation__background: @color-white;
//Change the link color
@link__color: @color-white;
```

> b) app/design/frontend/Packt/compstore/web/css/_style.less

_style.less code is as follows

```
    @import 'source/lib/_lib.less';
@import 'source/_sources.less';
@import 'source/_components.less';
@import 'source/helloworld.less';
```

> c) app/design/frontend/Packt/helloworld/web/css/source/helloworld.less

hellowworld.less code is as follows

```
 @color-compstore: #000;

body{
background: @color-compstore;
}
```

The theme is not adding the background color black and the link color which is white.

Please help me solve this